# how can i ensure that there are no duplicates entries being posted into the table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Values are added to the database, via dynamic table and posted using codeigniter :

```
$counter = count($this->input->post('mail_group'));
for($x = 0; $x < $counter; $x++ ){
    $this->db->insert('mail_groups_req', [
        'mail_groups_mail_group_id' => $this->input->post('mail_group')[$x],
        'requests_request_id'       => $request_id,
        'requests_uars_uars_id'     => $this->input->post('requestor_id'),
        'requests_users_user_id'    => $user_id,
    ]);
}
```

How can I ensure that there are no duplicates entries being posted into the table?

Comment: Either query the database for the dup before inserting, or make a relevant column unique which will error on an attempt to insert a dup

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in validation rule for that: is_unique.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference

> Returns FALSE if the form element is not unique to the table and field
>   name in the parameter. Note: This rule requires Query Builder to be
>   enabled in order to work.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mail_group', 'Mail Group', 'required|is_unique[users.mail_group]');
```